# Fit to height of browser's window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achieve the following layout with 100% height to browser.

[image]

Only the content area should be scrollable, when required and footer should be display at the bottom of browser.

But after tried many times i got this one

[image]

by using following code.

```
html { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}

#header, #footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    background-color: #808080;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 999px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**//HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Satkar Travels</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="ltc, travel, Satkar Travels, lfc, Satkar Parivar, Satkar Holidays, Satkar Travels Gurgaon">
        <meta name="description" content="A Leader in LTC Travel.">
        <meta name="author" content="Satkar Travels">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <section>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </section>
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <br><br>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

please help
Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the `height` for the `html` tag. And make the `wrapper` height equal to the `body` minus the height of `header` and `footer`. Or remove the `header` and `footer`

Comment: Totally unrelated but do consider using something other than IE.

Comment: Make header and footer to position : fixed and then give them height. For header make top:0 and for footer make your bottom:0

Comment: @PatsyIssa look in his taskbar he has 4 different browsers right there, with chrome and opera even being active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use fixed position, to align the header and footer at the top and bottom. Then just leave the content with a margin-top to keep it below the header.

**HTML:**

```
<header></header>
<div id="mainContent">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

div#mainContent {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w22dr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 51px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: -450px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

And then this:

```
<div class="header"> </div>
<div class="container"> </div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxL7s/

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change in CSS.
Example: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5F7YG/)

or

Apply this css:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}

#header{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100px;*/
    background-color: #808080;

}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#808080;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 999px;
    margin: auto;
}
```